# td height in Firefox unable to change

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe, html-table

The issue is that the td height is being stretched out like this image demonstrates:

[image]

I have tried the following:

1. setting the td height to 1px and allowing the content to stretch it.
2. adding a style and setting the height to 1 px
3. adding a div tag on the content within the td and setting the div tag height and overflow hidden
4. styling the td to have an overflow hidden
5. styling the td with `display: block`
6. Setting the vertical-align to top

I think the problem may be the iframe which is set to auto resize depending on the content within the iframe.

None of which seemed to help the page is here http://soldbybillcox.com/listings.html

I'm very aware that sites should be made with divs and using tables is outdated!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the code you used for the image? That would make debugging easier.

Comment: this is kind of difficult to do otherwise i would have i did post the site! I dont believe the problem to be an easy one so i think its directly related to my entire code! My believe is that its got to do with an iframe but i just dont know how ever here is a fiddle open it in chrome vs ff its vastly different http://jsfiddle.net/CLMLV/3/\ @ShaquinTrifonoff

Comment: By the way, why *can't* you use `<div>`s?

Comment: This appears to fix the problem (at least the one in your screenshot): http://jsfiddle.net/apac9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you asked this question before as well but no one gave an answer there. I had replied there about using divs for layouts, though.

Anyway, I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to solve it. 
Is this what you need ? try opening in firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/CLMLV/

Comment: that is what i need however i cant find on my page why any of these "fixes" dont work @Aditya Saxena

Comment: This is very odd to me and is indeed a perfect exaple of why to move to divs but this would still leave me scratching my head which is ultimately the point now!

Comment: I think you have to ensure that your colspans and rowspans calculate to the total number of columns ideally. Table's are a tricky business and you'd have to check this. I didn't see this happening on your site when i checked it yesterday.

Comment: probably because you were not using ff i have never gotten this page to render correctly in ff! thanks though i will recount for good measures

Comment: @tman did you find anything missing with the number of td colspans or rowspans ?